# Increment index of a Javascript function's argument name dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In this code javascript function is taking from[1] as argument in displayDatePicker('from[1]', false, 'dmy', '-'). When I clone this (second) row using jquery, all my input and select names get incremented but javascript function is still taking from[1] as argument. I want to ask how to change this from[1] to from[2] and so on

```
<tr>
         <td width="19%" align="right" ><input type="text" id="roomcat" name="roomcat[1]" value="Deluxe" /></td>
         <td width="1%" align="center" >&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="15%" align="left" ><select class="f" name="roomtype[1]" id="roomtype">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
            <option value="Double">Double</option>
            <option value="Triple">Triple</option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
         </select></td>
         <td width="7%" align="left" ><input type="text" id="cfit" name="cfit[1]" /></td>
         <td width="8%" align="left" ><input type="text" id="cgit" name="cgit[1]" /></td>
         <td width="7%" align="center" ><input type="text" id="rfit" name="rfit[1]" /></td>
         <td width="8%" align="center" ><input type="text" id="rgit" name="rgit[1]" /></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center" >
            <input class="f" style="width:70px" type="text" size="12" name="from[1]" id="from" value="<?php if($mode==1)
            {
            echo $from;
            }
            else
            {
            echo "From";
            }?>" readonly="readonly"  />
            <a href="javascript:displayDatePicker('from[1]', false, 'dmy', '-')"><i.m.g alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.g.i.f" border="0" width="17" height="16" /></a>
         </td>
         <td width="10%" align="center" >
            <input style="width:70px" class="f" type="text" size="12" name="to[1]" id="to" value="<?php if($mode==1)
              {
              echo $to;
              }
              else
              {
              echo "To";
              }?>" readonly="readonly" />
              <a href="javascript:displayDatePicker('to[1]', false, 'dmy', '-')"><i.m.g alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.g.i.f" border="0" width="17" height="16"  /></a>
         </td>
         <td width="15%" align="left" >&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
```

Jquery Code is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addrow").click(function() {
      var row = $('#table2 tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
        row.find("input:text").each(function(){
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/, function(str,p1){
            return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
        });
        })
    row.find("select").each(function(){
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/, function(str,p1){
            return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
        });
        })
      row.insertAfter('#table2 tbody>tr:last');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why not bind a click handler to your `<a>`s using jQuery? That would make this pretty easy.

Comment: @mu thank you for edit. Please tell how to bind it because I am new to both jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `id` attributes in your `<input>`s, you don't need them and having duplicate `id`s just leaves you with invalid HTML and strange problems. If you're using them for styling, use classes instead. If you need them for something else, then you'll have to fix them when you copy so that you don't end up with duplicate `id`s.

Now we can clean up your cloning a little bit. When you're cloning your row, you don't need to parse the number in brackets, you can just ask the table how many rows it has and add one to get the new number:

```
var n = $('#table2 tbody>tr').length + 1;
```

then your [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) calls simplify to this:

```
this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/, '[' + n + ']');
```

Also, you can use a [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to iterate through the `<input>`s and the `<select>`s at the same time:

```
row.find('input:text, select').each(...)
```

You're changing the same attribute in both cases so there's no need for two identical loops.

Using `javascript:displayDatePicker(...)` in your `<a>` isn't necessary. You can use jQuery to bind to clicks on those `<a>`s by adding a class to them:

```
<a class="datepicker">...</a>
```

and then binding a callback to them using [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and a [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) combination inside the callback will let you find the corresponding `<input>`:

```
$('a.datepicker').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).closest('td').find('input[type=text]');
    displayDatePicker($input.attr('name'), false, 'dmy', '-'));
});
```

You're using [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) so the event handlers on the cloned elements will be copied so you don't have to mess around with [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or the dynamic versions of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Here's a demo with simplified HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yEaw6/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer with a great explanation. It resolved my problem and also helped me understand what i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from the first paragraph in your question..

Will this help?

```
var cells = $('td');  //Select row/cells here

$.each(cells, function(index, cell){
  //index corresponds to index of current cell in set of matched cells  
});
```