# How I clone html codes group box with change its name and id

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I use this code for my form. I actually find some codes for clone with jQuery some of these box but I can not clone all of them with change its name and id for each box please help me to solve this problem.

```
<!-- table -->

                    <div class="pozisyon-kapsa deneyimForm">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8k">
                            <div id="isim" class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>İsim</h5>
                                    <input type="text" class="with-border">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pozisyon-kapsa deneyimForm">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8k">
                            <div id="soyisim" class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>Soyisim</h5>
                                    <input type="text" class="with-border">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pozisyon-kapsa deneyimForm">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8k">
                            <div id="soyisim" class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>Doğum Yeri</h5>
                                    <input type="text" class="with-border">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="pozisyon-kapsa deneyimForm">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8k">
                            <div class="submit-field">
                                <h5>Doğum Tarihi</h5>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="date-cl">
                                <input type="date" id="inputMDEx1" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pozisyon-kapsa deneyimForm">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8k">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>cinsiyet</h5>
                                    <select class="chosen with-border" data-size="7" title="Select Job Type">
                                        <option selected disabled style="display:none"> Seçiniz </option>
                                        <option>Erkek</option>
                                        <option>Kadın</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                    <!-- table -->
```

I have also some good source for this one

1. http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yEaw6/
2. [Increment index of a Javascript function's argument name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426091/increment-index-of-a-javascript-functions-argument-name-dynamically)
3. [How to add name attribute of input field dynamically using Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968875/how-to-add-name-attribute-of-input-field-dynamically-using-javascript-jquery/37969113#37969113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery, and only cloning for all of the elements, u can clone it this way

```
var cloneElements = $('.deneyimForm').clone();
```

Since we dont know which element name or id you want to change.
So i just take input as the element u want to select.

```
 cloneElements.each(function(){
    var inputElement = $(this).find('input');
    if(inputElement.length > 0){ //check if input element exist
        inputElement.attr('id','inputID');
        inputElement.attr('name','inputName');
    }
 });
```

Now all the input element inside the cloned elements (all of them) have the same input name and input id.

Comment: thank I find a solution but also I have another problem with same codes

Comment: By the way, how can I add my harvest script file from the internet with append() code?